# jetty maven plugin in multi-module maven app

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I have the maven spring application with such structure:

```
root
    -core
    -ws
       -endpoints
       -webapp
```

Core module contains business logic

Endpoints module contains classes @WebService

Webapp module contains web.xml

Endpoins module has several beans.

My web.xml has link to main context:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

applicationContext.xml imports context of Endpoints module

```
<import resource="classpath:ws-context.xml"/>
```

I can launch the application in two ways:

1. By Idea run configuration (jetty with artifcat)
2. By jetty-maven-plugin (eclispe)

When I run it by Idea everything is ok. When I use jetty-maven-plugin I have following problem:

Spring finds ws-context.xml, but he doesn't read it. I have found out it by two experiments:

1.I remamed ws-context.xml and spring failed with error.

2.I made ws-context.xml invalid and spring didn't fail.

Unfortunately, I've lost my beans. What is wrong?

Jetty version 9+ (I tried different). My jetty config is below:

```
                <configuration>
                    <war>${project.basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</war>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <force>true</force>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>jetty.home</name>
                            <value>/</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <webApp>
                        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                        <extraClasspath>${basedir}/../../config/</extraClasspath>
                    </webApp>
                </configuration>
```

Comment: Could it be the `jetty.home` ?

Comment: do you see any error or stack trace ?

Comment: No errors. I tried to reproduce on other computer, but there is all ok. So it seems to be local problem.